# What is span of $V = \{v \in \mathbb{R}^2 | v=(a, b), a=5\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

What is span of $V = \{v \in \mathbb{R}^2 | v=(a, b), a=5\}$?

I am not sure about this because span can not be something like $\{(5,1)\}$ because that will include for example $(25,5)$ which I don't want. I want first element not to change but I do not know how.
What is base of V?

Comment: The span of $V$ has to *contain* $V$, not to be contained in $V$. So it may perfectly contain $(25,5)$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe what will be base then?

Comment: **Hint :** $V$ contains $(5,1)$ and $(5,0)$ which are linearly independant. What can you say of the span in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of a set that contains a basis ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Basis will be $ \{(5,b)| b\in \mathbb{R} \}$ but I want that written down as span and I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Note that $(5,1)$ and $(5,2)\in V$. And that any vector in $\mathbb R^2$ can be written as $s(5,1)+t(5,2)$ for some $s,t\in\mathbb R$

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be interpreting $V$ to be a vector space. However, it cannot be a vector space, because it's missing something *very* important. (Can you see what?)

Given that, $V$ does not *have* a base. However, it *contains* a base for its *span*, which *is* a vector space.

To see what its span is, note that $V$ has cardinality greater than $1,$ and that any two vectors of $V$ are linearly independent. (Can you see why?) Thus, since $\Bbb R^2$ has dimension $2,$ there is only one possible span that $V$ can have.

Answer (score 0):

The set $V$ is precisely the set $\{{(5,b)|b\in\mathbb R\}}$ in space $\mathbb R^2$, which itself is an *affine space*. The span($V$) is the set obtained by the linear combination $$ {\sum_i k_iv_i}$$

which incorporates  the missing zero vector in this affine space and all vectors of the form $(\alpha, b), \alpha\ne 5$ as well. So span($V$)=....